# How to add/draw an arrow or other object to quantmod package chart

Tags: r, quantmod

I would like to add objects that present signals on quantmod chart, How can I do that.For example I have two signals for an IBM chart:

```
    library("quantmod")
    getSymbols("IBM")
    IBM$LastDay_green<- ifelse((lag(IBM$IBM.Open,k=1) < lag(IBM$IBM.Close,k=1)),1,0)
    IBM$LastDay_red<- ifelse((lag(IBM$IBM.Open,k=1) > lag(IBM$IBM.Close,k=1)),1,0)
```

How can I add a green object / arrow  below the candle that is `IBM$LastDay_green==1` and how can I add a red object / arrow  above the candle that is `IBM$LastDay_red==1`